# Detecting very unusual words with pocketsphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am working on a project that requires keyword detection with pocketsphinx running on a raspberry pi. For my project, the keywords are very unusual/completely made up so that it's unlikely they are heard outside of this specific use case. Would adapting the existing english acoustic model be enough for this situation given enough data? If not, how else can I tackle this issue?

Comment: do you have the phonetic representation of the keywords? if you just add those to the lexicon/dictionary it should work ok. especially if you limit the dictionary to only a few hundred words. can you query the cloud for the detection or do you have to do local detection?

Comment: @deef I'll try the phonetic represenations. We can probably query the cloud but it would have to be very quick.

Comment: if you are interested in querying the cloud I am working on an API for this exact thing (recognition of weird/made up words) ... https://docs.assemblyai.com/ -- if you want to try it to see if it works for you let me know

Comment: @deef Your api looks amazing! Thanks for sharing it. I'll try it out and let you know.